# Fix MIME_HTML_ONLY on email template

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to fix `MIME_HTML_ONLY` to pass some spam filter, the email is sent from a php project and I use this  template

```
<html>    
    <table width="100%" style="font-family: Verdana; color: #707070" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="643" align="center">
                    <tr style="text-align: center">
                        <td style="padding: 0 20px;">
                            {% block top %}{% endblock %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color: #005aff; text-align: center;">
                        <td>
                            <img src="https://www.mydomain/dist/imgs/cabecera.png"  atl="cabecera-encueston" style="width: 643px; height: 100px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 20px;">
                            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% if external is defined %}
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 20px;">
                            <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #707070;  padding: 20px 20px 0; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                Un saludo,<br>
                            </p>
                            <img src="https://www.mydomain/dist/imgs/firma.png" atl="firma" style="width: 643px; height: 100px">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 20px;">
                            <img src="https://www.mydomain/dist/imgs/siguenos.png" alt="siguenos" style="width: 643px; height: 56px">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr style="color: #ccc; text-align: center;">
                        <td style="padding: 0 20px; text-alig: center;">
                            {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;">&copy; Encuestón S.L.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<html>
```

,
I'm not sure to fix `MIME_HTML_ONLY` issue,I've to change the solution is "You should also includea text version of your message (text/plain)"  but how?

Comment: If you are using PHPs `mail()` you should not use it for production because its commonly filtered by spam filters. Use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) libraries to send mail. In PHPMailer you can then set an `AltBody` which can contain the email content in plain text.

Comment: I'm using SwiftMailer

Comment: Are you sending the mails over smtp?
You can call `setBody` with a 2nd argument to pass it an HTML body.
[SwiftMailer - Creating Messages](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html)

Comment: I used SwiftMailer `addPart` function  to add an alternative pain text body and  it's solved

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is not in your HTML, but in your lack of a text alternative.**

You should build **a text representation** of your e-mail message, and add it as an alternative.

Then, provide it to your mailer:

- SwiftMailer from symfony: you need to use `addPart` with a text representation of your message
- With PHPMailer, it's the `AltBody` part of your mail

When sending a mail, you can specify to send it in HTML or in text.
When e-mail has been created, all e-mails were simply text, but then mailers added capabilities to send e-mail in HTML, so that you can add bold, italic, images, etc.

To be sure that mails were readable by everyone, the same mail was in 2 parts : HTML and text, so that the mailer could display the format it supports.

Fast forward today, all mailers support HTML, and the legacy text part is not really needed. For spammers, sending millions of spam with less characters is a huge saving of bandwidth. So they remove the text part, and spam can be detected by this difference.

`MIME_HTML_ONLY` comes from the fact **you only have HTML in your mail**, and thus it seems fishy for spam filters.